# Spring validation in multiple forms

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, validation

Can we display error messages in one jsp but in 2 different forms.I am validating my bean using spring validation.Its working fine but if there is an error in the binding results then I am able to display the error message in the form from where action is executed but not in the other resultant form.

is the error tag in spring validation is mapped to jsp form from where that action is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your BindingResults is just an object, which you can put in your Model and use on the page however you want.  You may need to put it into Session if you plan to use it on a separate form.